# How to get input value based on option value selected?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

> I have a dynamic input form like this (open the link): [this is the
>   form](https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-Mah_Y7PqhBI/WOuYfb-Co4I/AAAAAAAACDc/3LbFEokgo4g1zfejivYj0YhWyvq2WKsCwCLcB/s1600/table%2Binput.PNG)

The option value is "Debit" and "Kredit".

In my case, I wanna get the Jumlah's value based on the option selected. As you can see in that picture, in first row, I input the Jumlah's value with 10 and then I select the "Debit", so the Total Debit value will change to 10 and Total Kredit value still 0.

And then, in the next row, I input the Jumlah's value with 3 and then I select "Kredit", so the Total Debit value still 10 and Total Kredit change to 3.

Then, when I change the second row to Debit, the Total Debit should be 13 and Total Kredit is 0. But, it makes Total Debit to 13 and Total Kredit still 3.

So, how can I solve this? Any suggestions or another alternatives?

Here is my form's code:

```
<form action="" method="post">
  {{ csrf_field() }}
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="nojurnal">Nomor Jurnal:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nojurnal" value="{{ $noJurnal+1 }}" name="no_jurnal" readonly>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="tgljurnal">Tanggal Jurnal:</label>
    <input type="date" class="form-control" id="tgljurnal" name="tgl_jurnal">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="keterangan">Keterangan:</label>
    <textarea name="keterangan_jurnal" id="keterangan" class="form-control" rows="8" cols="80"></textarea>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <div class="form-group table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-striped">
      <thead>
        <th>Nomor Rekening</th>
        <th>Nama Rekening</th>
        <th>Keterangan</th>
        <th>Jumlah</th>
        <th>Jenis Rekening</th>
        <th></th>
      </thead>
      <tbody class="tabel-body">
        <tr class="row-rekening">
          <td>
            <div class="form-group">
              <select class="form-control kodeRekening" name="kode_rekening[]">
                @foreach($rekenings as $rekening)
                  <option class="listKodeRekening" value="{{ $rekening->kode_rekening }}" nm="{{ $rekening->nama_rekening }}">{{ $rekening->kode_rekening }}</option>
                @endforeach
              </select>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div class="form-group">
              <input class="form-control namaRekening" type="text" name="" value="" readonly>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div class="form-group">
              <input class="form-control keterangan" type="text" name="keterangan[]" value="">
            </div>
          </td>

          <td>
            <div class="form-group">
              <input class="form-control jumlahDK" type="text" name="jumlah[]" value="">
            </div>
          </td>

          <td>
            <div class="form-group">
              <select class="form-control jenisRekening" name="d_k[]">
                <option value="">-- Pilih --</option>
                <option value="D" class="debit">Debit</option>
                <option value="K" class="kredit">Kredit</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </td>

          <td>
            <div class="form-group">
              <button type="button" class="form-control glyphicon glyphicon-plus btn-success more-input" name="button"></button>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>

      </tbody>
    </table>

  </div>

  <div class="form-group col-sm-12">
    <label for="total-debit" class="col-sm-2">Total Debit</label>
    <span class="col-sm-4"><input type="text" id="jumlah-debit" class="form-control" name="" value="" readonly></span>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group col-sm-12">
    <label for="total-kredit" class="col-sm-2">Total Kredit</label>
    <span class="col-sm-4"><input type="text" id="jumlah-kredit" class="form-control" name="" value="" readonly></span>
  </div>

  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Simpan">
</form>
```

And this is my javascript code:

```
$(document).on('change', '.jenisRekening', function(e){
if ($(this).val()=='D' && $(this).parent().parent().prev().find('.jumlahDK').val() !==''){
    totalDebit += parseInt($(this).parent().parent().prev().find('.jumlahDK').val())
}
else if($(this).val()=='K' && $(this).parent().parent().prev().find('.jumlahDK').val() !==''){
    totalKredit += parseInt($(this).parent().parent().prev().find('.jumlahDK').val())
}
$('#jumlah-debit').val(totalDebit)
$('#jumlah-kredit').val(totalKredit)
```

});

Answer (score 0):

The variables `totalDebit` and `totalCredit` should be reinitialised to zero in your jQuery code before they're recomputed. It seems that their old value is retained and therefore a simple solution would be:

```
$(document).on('change', '.jenisRekening', function(e){
    totalDebit = 0;
    totalKredit = 0;

    if ($(this).val()=='D' && $(this).parent().parent().prev().find('.jumlahDK').val() !==''){
        totalDebit += parseInt($(this).parent().parent().prev().find('.jumlahDK').val());
    }
    else if($(this).val()=='K' && $(this).parent().parent().prev().find('.jumlahDK').val() !==''){
        totalKredit += parseInt($(this).parent().parent().prev().find('.jumlahDK').val());
    }

    $('#jumlah-debit').val(totalDebit);
    $('#jumlah-kredit').val(totalKredit); 
});
```